# What is the format for combining several Parameters in RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use the current `[OR]` but also add: `[L,R=301,NC]` for a permanent redirect.

So is that `[OR, L,R=301,NC]`?

Comment: Just to clarify, what you asking about are _flags_, not _parameters_. The whole _flags_ argument is _one parameter_ to the `RewriteCond` directive (regardless of how many _flags_ you are including).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) say that the flags are a comma-separated list.

But only OR and NC are flags for RewriteCond. R and L are flags for RewriteRule, so you wouldn't put them together with OR and NC.

Comment: "a comma-separated list" - and _no spaces_ (unlike the OPs example).